# How Search in value Api Content by use .net core controller

Tags: c#, .net, api, controller

I used This controller for .net core

```
  string url = "Url Here";
        private string customerApi;
        private object JsonRequestBehavior;

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Getagent")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Getagent(string search)
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(customerApi);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return Content(jsondata, "application/json");
                }


                return Ok();

            }
        }
```

outputs values as array >> how i serach in this array by Api controller Web Api

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service at customerApi doesn't accept search strings and you want to do the search locally, you have to create a model that represent the data of the json. For example you get this json from the service:

```
{
  "name": "John Smith",
  "id": 1,
  "age": 20,
  "tags": [
     "person", "male", "etc"
  ]
}
```

You have to create an object model like this:

```
public class ServiceResponseModel {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
  public string[] Tags {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can convert json into an array of these objects:

```
  string jsondata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var responseObject=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsondata);
```

If you got the object, you can search in its properties:

```
  var filteredResponseObject = responseObject.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(search))
```